# Javascript cannot change the value of mydata

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this code:

```
mydata: null | { id: string } = null;
```

And after I try to add some values:

```
this.mydata.id = 'myidstring';
```

I keep getting:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of null
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's the content of `mydata` after you did `this.mydata = null` ? cmon this is programming 101...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a property on `null`. You need to assign an object to your variable first:

```
let mydata: null | { id: string } = null;

mydata = {};
mydata.id = 'myidstring';
```

Or all in one go:

```
let mydata: null | { id: string } = null;

mydata = {
  id: 'myidstring'
};
```